# presentModalViewController doesn't work

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

```
-(void)backAction:(id)sender
{ 
   SecondViewController *viewCtrl = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

   [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

   [self.presentingViewController presentModalViewController:viewCtrl animated:YES];
}
```

I want to `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` the current controller,then present a new controller. But it only `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO`.

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line, you are already dismissing the view controller

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Then in the next line you are trying to preset a modal view using the view controller that was already dismissed.

```
[self.presentingViewController presentModalViewController:viewCtrl animated:YES];
```

Instead try presenting the modal view using a the parent view controller (if you have any) of both these views. You can also fire a notification to your parent view controller after dismissing the first view so that you can launch the second modal view from the parent view controller.

Answer (score 1):

self.presentingViewController will be nil after you dismiss yourself in the first line. So all you have to do is get a direct reference to whatever that controller is before you do the dismissal. In the following example, the presenting view controller is of the ViewController class. You will have to use what ever class is your actual presenting view controller.

```
-(void)backAction:(id)sender {
     ViewController *presenter = (ViewController *)self.presentingViewController; 
     SecondViewController *viewCtrl = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

     [presenter dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
     [presenter presentModalViewController:viewCtrl animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    [self.presentingViewController presentModalViewController:viewCtrl animated:YES];
}]
```